# TabBarController - reload SecondViewController

Tags: ios

I am making a TabBarController application using the template provided by Xcode and I need to reload the second view controller everytime it is clicked. How do I do this ?

Thanks

Comment: I need to refresh the ViewController with new data.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever the tab bar switches the view controllers, the viewcontroller `viewWillAppear` function will be called

So add the code in the `viewWillAppear` function of the `UIViewController`